# detecting if a part of a string matches another string

Tags: oracle

hi guys this is the question:

Display the employee ID and email of employees whose email address has their full last name in it.

what do you think can I use? Can I use substr? if not, any other suggestions? Thanks guys peace!

Comment: Basic SQL will suffice.  No need for string functions.

Comment: Just bang it out and let it run; substr or whatever you have in mind, its the fastest way you will learn =)

Comment: @LolCoder I tried something. ^^ Can you tell me if the code works?  Because I don't have Oracle. :'<

Answer (score 0):

I'd use regular expressions, for example

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
  emp_id     NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name VARCHAR2(30),
  last_name  VARCHAR2(30),
  email      VARCHAR2(255)
);

INSERT INTO employees VALUES (1, 'Joseph', 'Ratzinger', 'benedictxvi@vatican.va');
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (2, 'Tim', 'Cook', 'tcook@apple.com');
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (3, 'Larry', 'Ellison', 'Ellison@oracle.com');
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (4, 'Michael', 'Dell', 'Michael@dell.com');

SELECT emp_id, email FROM employees WHERE regexp_like(email, last_name);
3 Ellison@oracle.com
```

To include case independent results, use:

```
SELECT emp_id, email FROM employees WHERE regexp_like(email, last_name, 'i');
2 tcook@apple.com
3 Ellison@oracle.com
4 Michael@dell.com
```

If you need to exclude the hostname, either append an '@' to the pattern ...

```
SELECT emp_id, email FROM employees WHERE regexp_like(email, last_name||'@', 'i');
2 tcook@apple.com
3 Ellison@oracle.com
```

... or extract the hostname from the email:

```
SELECT emp_id, email 
  FROM employees 
 WHERE regexp_like(regexp_substr(email,'.*@'), last_name, 'i');
```